# Trying to create two new array of object using reduce but not getting the output

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

```
let obj =[
    {
        "SID": 123,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test123",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 1
    },
    {
        "SID": 543,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1543",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 2
    },
    {
        "SID": 454,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1454",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 3
    },
    {
        "SID": 789,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1789",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 4
    },
    {
        "SID": 999,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1999",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 5
    },
    {
        "SID": 555,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1555",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 6
    },
    ]

let sidNumbers = "789,543,123";

function newArr(arr, obj){
    let newwArr = [];
    let splitArr = arr.split(',');
    splitArr.reduce((curr, acc)=>{
        if(`${acc['SID']}`.includes(curr))
        {
            newwArr.push(acc)
        }
    },obj)
    return newwArr;
}

console.log(newArr(sidNumbers, obj));

the first output firstArray = [{
        "SID": 789,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1789",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 4
    },
    {
        "SID": 543,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1543",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 2
    },
    {
        "SID": 123,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test123",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 1
    }
]

the output of secondArray =[
 
    {
        "SID": 454,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1454",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 3
    },
    {
        "SID": 999,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1999",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 5
    },
    {
        "SID": 555,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1555",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 6
    },
]
```

I have an array of object and string of numbers. Trying to create two new array of objects. first in which sidNumbers matches from the obj it filters an return the an array of object and in second the sidNumbers doesn't matches from the obj it filters an return the an array of object. Is using reduce is the best way to solve this problem or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: are you sure you are calling your function right? `console.log(newArr(arr, obj));` this gives errors, `arr` is undefined....you probably meant to type `console.log(newArr(sidNumbers, obj));` but then again if you fix that, the output is nowhere close to your expected output, and you are returning 1 array only, not 2. Also it is a bad practice to use `.reduce()` like that

Comment: I suggest you to user `Array.prototype.filter`

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `filter` instead of `reduce` to get a clearer code.

The only advantage of `reduce` is that it would iterate over the list only once, which only is relevant if you have a huge list (like, hundreds of thousands of elements)

In any case, here is how you could do I with `reduce`:

```
let [firstArray, secondArray] = obj.reduce(
  ([y,n], o) => sidNumbers.contains(o.SID) ? [[...y, o],n] : [y,[...n, o]], [[],[]]);
```

---

Notes on the code above:

- `[firstArray, secondArray] = ...` - this is destructuring assignment. It means that I expect that the result of the expression will be an array with 2 elements, so I am assigning the first element into the variable `firstArray` and the second to `secondArray`.
- `obj.reduce(([y,n], o) => ..., [[],[]])` - the function `reduce` takes 2 arguments. The first is a function and the second is the initial value (in this case, I am using an array of 2 empty arrays as initial value). The function must take 2 input parameters:

  - the accumulated aggregation so far (that I know is always an array with 2 elements, so I am destructuring them into 2 variables `y` and `n`
  - the current object `o` of the iteration over `obj`
- `sidNumbers.contains(o.SID)` - checking if the attribute `SID` of the current object is included in your `sidNumbers` list.
- `... ? [[...y, o],n] : [y,[...n, o]], [[],[]]` - this is the ternary conditional operator. If the condition returns `true`, the function will return the value before the colon `:`, which is just appending the current object `o` into the array `y`. If it is false, append `o` into the second array `n`.
- At the end, after iterating over the original list, all elements where the condition was true (i.e., their SID is contained in the reference list) will be aggregated in the first array, and the others on the second array.

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo..can you please explain a little about code?

Comment: sure, let me add an edit

Comment: Thanks you @Rodrigo and more thing, if we had array instead let string ("789,543,123");

Comment: It would probably work same way, ir with minimal changes. Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Use filter() and includes() instead of reduce(). Reduce is better suited for modifying elements to a new array.

```js
let obj =[
    {
        "SID": 123,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test123",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 1
    },
    {
        "SID": 543,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1543",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 2
    },
    {
        "SID": 454,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1454",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 3
    },
    {
        "SID": 789,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1789",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 4
    },
    {
        "SID": 999,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1999",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 5
    },
    {
        "SID": 555,
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Test1555",
        "EMPLOYEE_ID": 6
    },
    ]

const filterObjectsBySID = (obj, sidNumbers) =>
  [obj.filter(({ SID }) => sidNumbers.includes(SID.toString())),
  obj.filter(({ SID }) => !sidNumbers.includes(SID.toString()))];

const sidNumbers = "789,543,123";

const [matchingObjects, nonMatchingObjects] = filterObjectsBySID(obj, sidNumbers);

console.log(matchingObjects);
console.log(nonMatchingObjects);
```